# Spring not autowiring AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot in IntelliJ to create a Spring MVC project.
I'm using Spring security for authenticating users. I followed a guide found [here](https://github.com/hellokoding/registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql).

Here is my SecurityService class:

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService = new UserDetailsServiceImpl();

    public String findLoggedInUsername() {
        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
            return ((UserDetails)userDetails).getUsername();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void autologin(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if(userDetails.getUsername().equals("NotFound")) {
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have a these lines in defined in securityConfig.xml:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

In IntelliJ, next to the authenticationManager there is a bean icon and when I click it it directs me to the Bean definition of the AuthenticationManager.

However, when I try compiling, Spring gives me this error:

> Field authenticationManager in project.service.SecurityService
>   required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'
>   that could not be found.
>
> - Bean method 'authenticationManager' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types:
>     org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor;
>     SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans

Why can't Spring find the bean, when IntelliJ can? How do I fix this?

BTW most of my configuration is being done with Spring Boot Autoconfiguration. I've already tried adding @Qualifier("authenticationManager"), that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with `component-scan`. What you can do is in `securityConfig.xml` create the bean `SecurityService` as below.

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="securityService" class="SecurityService" />
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have included the whole xml file. I already have this line in my config file: <beans:bean id="securityService" class="project.service.SecurityService"></beans:bean>